# How to integrate a Coporate TeamViewer license into MSI package

Tags: license, teamviewer, integration

I'am in trouble since many hour with this : i want to integrate a license for my support team into a MSI package (with MECM). I've got this line of DOS working fine with my custom parameters :

*msiexec.exe /i "c:\tmp\Downloads\config TV\TeamViewer_Full.msi" /qn SETTINGSFILE="c:\tmp\Downloads\config TV\settings.tvopt" CUSTOMCONFIGID=XXXXX APITOCKEN=XXXXXX*

But when its installed, I just find my custom parameters, the license is still "free license for personnal use". Do you have an idea ?
I'am using version 15.4
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you contacted TeamViewer support to determine the reason your license isn’t being upgraded to a Corporate license as expected?

Comment: yeah, ive contacted the support, and they said me the previous version was able to export the licence in the MSI file, but not now, it's about security abviously....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way for distributing TeamViewer.

Instead of creating your own method, I suggest following the manual at
[Mass deployment on Windows - Overview](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/39639-mass-deployment-improvements).

This manual describes the process in 6 sections:

```
▸Step 1: Modules and deployment methods
▸Step 2: Create your custom module
▸Step 3: Recommended scripts
▸Step 4: Manage your settings
▸Step 5: Assignment options
▸Step 6: Keep your clients up-to-date
```